# Why is variable not global in BGE Python

Tags: python, game-engine, blender

I'm trying to make a simple game in Blender Game Engine using Python controller.

I have a Python controller attached to an Always sensor on a pulse mode and a game property called 'first' on a Sphere, which is also the controlled object.

I want to run a few lines of code only for the first time the game runs, just so it defines the variables and it doesn't overwrite them the next time it runs.

When I run the code below I get an error, that the `ForBack` and `LeftRight` variables are not defined. However I can access them from within the if statement.

Am I missing something obvious or what? Also let me know if I could compact this code.

```
import bge
from bge import logic

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
player = cont.owner
keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
objs = scene.objects
ACTIVE = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE
first = objs['Sphere']['first']

if(first == True):
    ForBack = 0.0
    LeftRight = 0.0
    print('1')
    print(ForBack)
    objs['Sphere']['first'] = False

if (keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY] == ACTIVE and ForBack < 50):
    ForBack += 5
    #forward   
if (keyboard.events[bge.events.SKEY] == ACTIVE and ForBack > -50):
    ForBack -= 5
    #backward
if (keyboard.events[bge.events.AKEY] == ACTIVE and LeftRight < 50):        
    LeftRight += 5
    #left
if (keyboard.events[bge.events.DKEY] == ACTIVE and LeftRight > -50):
    LeftRight -=5
    #right

player.applyTorque((ForBack, LeftRight, 0), False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are only defined if your first if statement  evaluates to `True`. You access every time  in all your if statements which are evaluated each time and in `player.applyTorque((ForBack, LeftRight, 0), False)`.

You should set the initial value for both **outside** the first if statement.

```
ForBack = 0.0
LeftRight = 0.0

if first: 
   ........
```

What is happening is pretty clear:

```
if(first == True): # evaluates to false first time
    ForBack = 0.0
    LeftRight = 0.0
    print('1')
    print(ForBack)
    objs['Sphere']['first'] = False

# then you get here and ForBack is not defined
if (keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY] == ACTIVE and ForBack < 50):
                                                    ^^^^^^
```

If you only want the others evaluate if the initial if statement is True you need to nest the if's inside the initial if.

```
if first == True:
    ForBack = 0.0
    LeftRight = 0.0
    print('1')
    print(ForBack)
    objs['Sphere']['first'] = False

    if (keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY] == ACTIVE and ForBack < 50):
        ForBack += 5
        #forward   
    if (keyboard.events[bge.events.SKEY] == ACTIVE and ForBack > -50):
        ForBack -= 5
        #backward
    if (keyboard.events[bge.events.AKEY] == ACTIVE and LeftRight < 50):        
        LeftRight += 5
        #left
    if (keyboard.events[bge.events.DKEY] == ACTIVE and LeftRight > -50):
        LeftRight -=5
        #right

    player.applyTorque((ForBack, LeftRight, 0), False)
```

Comment: I might use your advice, but the `print('1')` function stil runs and prints out '1'. So that means that teh whole `if` statement is evaluated True from the very begining and therefore, both variables should be defined.

Comment: The only way your code could error is  if  that if evaluates to False initially unless whatever version of python you are using behaves completely different to anything I have ever seen

Comment: It got me realy confused, because it always printed out '1', and the boolean property was set to True and I asumed that the if function runs and then sets the property to false so it doesn't run again. Later I actualy found out that the property is for whatever reason always False, even though I clearly set it to True. But thanks for advice. It's more fail proof.